# Show that any finite set S $\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ is the zero set of two homogeneous polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm currently working through Shafarevich - Basic Algebraic Geometry and I have the problem that I can't extend the results from $\mathbb{A}^2$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$. Could anyone help me?

Comment: An informal argument (I think it could be transformed into something rigourous with dual projectives spaces) : assume you have points $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Then you can find $k$ hypersurfaces which contains then. For $k$ enough big this system will not admit other solutions (use linear algebra).

Answer (score 4):

First, I assume that you are working over $\mathbb{C}$ (or an algebraically closed field), since even for one closed point, this is not known, if you are working over $\mathbb{Q}$. (This is a question due to Gennady Lyubeznik).

Over complex numbers, there are many proofs. Let me describe an elementary one. First, we may assume that $x_n=(0,1,0)$ and no other point lies on $z=0$. Next, we may change co-ordinates suitably (for instance $x\mapsto x+az, y\mapsto y+bz$, thus not changing the previous constraint) and assume that the $x$-cordinates of all the remaining points are distinct. So, $x_i=(a_i,b_i,1)$, for $i<n$, $a_i$s distinct. Then you can find a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n-2$ so that $b_i=p(a_i)$ for all $i<n$. Now, it is easy to check that $\prod(x-a_iz)$ and $yz^{n-3}-p(x,z)$ will do the trick, where $p(x,z)$ is the homogenization of $p(x)$.